# How Do I Fully Customize Angular Material Subheader Component?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, material-design, angularjs-material

Hi I'm very confused about how to style angular material components (angular 1.4).

I basically took the source code from the material site here and dropped it in my project:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/subheader

I wanted a list with sticky headers so this component is perfect. However, I need the colors to be different- very different.

[image]

For example, I need the background to be transparent dark gray and the text to be light gray.

If possible, I'd like to change the scroller thumb color too. So, is this even possible? I tried using a custom theme, but it seems to only affect the header color.

Comment: Just like anything else...inspect the css rules that apply to it in browser dev tools element inspector and add new rules accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded the whole pack you will find in the /modules/closure a directory list of all the components. In the subheader folder you can find the subheader-default-theme.css file.

```
.md-subheader.md-THEME_NAME-theme {
color: '{{ foreground-2-0.23 }}';
background-color: '{{background-color}}'; }
.md-subheader.md-THEME_NAME-theme.md-primary {
 color: '{{primary-color}}'; }
.md-subheader.md-THEME_NAME-theme.md-accent {
 color: '{{accent-color}}'; }
.md-subheader.md-THEME_NAME-theme.md-warn {
 color: '{{warn-color}}'; }
```

add it to your material_custom.css

set these to the values you prefer and then use the md-THEME_NAME_YOU_CHOOSE on the elements you need.

If you need further styling, inspect the element and add the style in the themes you already set.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answering, but I'm still having problems. I see this subheader-default-theme.css file in the material framework. Are you showing me this because I should change it or just so I know what css classes to override? Also, I'm using gulp and less without much knowledge of how they work. When use the <link> tag to drop a new stylesheet in the project and put colors in like "  .md-subheader.md-default-theme {color: red;}" it still doesn't work for me. : /